# Can't figure out how to change State in reducer without causing a mutation

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, immutability

I keep getting the following error thrown after trying to update state in my reducer:

> "Error: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path:
>   `quiz.questions.0.answer`. Take a look at the reducer(s) handling the
>   ac..."

I'm pretty sure I am not mutating the original state as I am using object.assign yet the error persists.

My reducer:

```
    case types.UPDATE_QUIZ_ANSWER:
        let newStateObject =  Object.assign({}, state);
        let currentQuestion = newStateObject.questions.find(x => x.id == parseInt(action.data.questionId));
        currentQuestion.answer = action.data.answer;
        return Object.assign({}, newStateObject);
```

My state object:

```
{"questions":
    [{"id":1,"questionText":"Camps is?","multipleChoiceOption1":
     {"value":"1","label":"Great"},"multipleChoiceOption2":
     {"value":"2","label":"Fun"},"multipleChoiceOption3":
     {"value":"3","label":"Awesome"},"multipleChoiceOption4":
     {"value":"4","label":"All of the above"},
     "answer":"2"},
     {"id":2,"questionText":"At Camps we will?","multipleChoiceOption1":
     {"value":"1","label":"AAA"},"multipleChoiceOption2":
     {"value":"2","label":"Adult Focused"},"multipleChoiceOption3":
     {"value":"3","label":"CCC"},"multipleChoiceOption4":
     {"value":"4","label":"All of the above"},
      "answer":"3"}],
  "results":
     {"quizPass":false,"quizResults":[]}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spread operator `...` aka `Object.assign` works only on the first level of object properties.

```
let newStateObject =  Object.assign({}, state);
let currentQuestion = newStateObject.questions.find(x => x.id == parseInt(action.data.questionId));
currentQuestion.answer = <----- here is the mutation
```

What you can do is to create a copy of object at each level:

```
// make a copy of the array
let newQuestions = [...newStateObject.questions];
let questionIndex = newQuestions.findIndex(x => x.id == parseInt(action.data.questionId));
// update array and question
newQuestions[questionIndex] = {...newQuestions[questionIndex], answer: action.data.answer};
// return new result
return  {...state, questions: newQuestions};
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is mutating your state:

```
let currentQuestion = newStateObject.questions.find(x => x.id ==
    parseInt(action.data.questionId));
currentQuestion.answer = action.data.answer;
```

`Object.assign` does not deep clone so, while your `newStateObject` is certainly not the same as your original `state`, the `currentQuestion` you are pulling from the array of `questions` *is* the same as in the original state object graph.

You may want to look into something like Immutable.js, but think about it like this: the actual object you want to change needs to be replaced, as does its parent (the object/array that references it) and so forth until the top of your state. If you are using `combineReducers` you only have to worry about the top of that *slice* since `combineReducers` does the work above that.

Comment: I am in fact using combine reduders,  but have cases for both question and result state changes in the same reducer as they both deal with actions generated in my quiz component but perhaps these should be handled by seperate reducers? Thanks for the suggestion on immutable.js, looking into it now